# VS2012 Intellisense configuration for C language

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense

My project is a static library and has a common .h file that will be used by both C and C++ versions, using the `_cplusplus` definition for correct section including.

I´m using VS2012 and when I set my project to use plain C language on **Project->Properties->C/C++->Advanced->Compile As->Compile As C Code (/TC)**, intellisense  still thinks I´m using C++ as the main language,

It gives me warnings on some C functions (like `strcpy_s`) and does not highlight sections defined by the `#ifndef _cplusplus` commands.

If I try to build or compile (F7) it works perfectly and it is compiled as a C project.

How can I tell intellisense to interpret the code as C language instead of C++ ?

Help appreciated...